# Inet6Address class in java : Global IPv6 address validation

Tags: java, ipv6

Since InetAddress does not have a method to determine if the given IPv6 address is global address or not can i assume a given IPv6 address is Global , if it is not site local and link local ?

```
Inet6Address addr = new Inet6Address(str);
boolean isGlobal = !addr.isSiteLocalAddress && !addr.isLinkLocalAddress;
```

Is this true ? can i safely use it ? or is there any other better way to determine the given IPv6 address is global address ?

Comment: yes you are rite ! let me edit that ! thanks anyway !